# Autohotkey ControlClick Only Works In Primary Window

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I have a Windows application that launches another window when a button is pressed. In the primary window [ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) works perfectly. In the spawned, secondary window ControlClick only works after manually pressing a button.

Code:

```
ControlFocus %classNN%, %winTitle%
ControlClick %classNN%, %winTitle%,,,, NA
```

And at the top of my thread I specify: `SetControlDelay, -1` as recommended by the documentation, but I've also tried setting it to 0 (lowest delay value rather than none).

I added the ControlFocus part in an attempt to focus on the button before pressing it.

Also, I'm on windows 7 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Unless you provide a [mcve] I can only guess. Maybe you are too fast and the secondary window hasn't created the button yet. Try to use [`WinWait`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) to wait until the button exists.

Comment: If I add a long Sleep it still doesn't work. But if I click on a button manually in the window, it does work.

Comment: @RyanHolmes As zett42 advised, we'll need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to properly help you.

Comment: Can you provide more details? (Name of the application, the window title, whether or not WinActivate works, etc)